# Secondary Memory Data Structures and allocation strategies for intermediate query results

Tags: data-structures, memory-management, database-theory, virtual-memory

Despite a huge amount of literature regarding table representation and indexing in secondary memory (also including database books), I found no information on how relational databases represent records generated from intermediate results in secondary memory. How are they representing this, thus considering that you might also generate new values or (e.g.,) json files, for which you might necessarily need to store variable size data within these records? Are they also using explicit resource allocation strategies for this?